# Hide labels on taskbar from registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, taskbar

I recently had an update on my work computer (Windows 7 Pro). After rebooting, i now have a problem with my taskbar icons: the labels are visible and buttons not groupping.

I want to restore the defaut behavior of Windows (hide labels and combine icons) but the option "Taskbar buttons" in the taskbar's "Properties" menu is disabled...

Is there a way to restore it directly by editing the registry ?

Answer (score 4):

Click on Start Menu, click Run, then type *regedit* and hit enter.
The key is located in,
**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced**

Locate the key *TaskbarGlomLevel* and change its value to 0, 1 or 2 as per your requirement.

To always combine, hide labels (default):
TaskbarGlomLevel = 0

Combine when taskbar is full:
TaskbarGlomLevel = 1

Never combine:
TaskbarGlomLevel = 2

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but the value is already on 0 for this key :/

Comment: Looks like your IT department locked it to "never combine" through a group policy. Whether the TaskbarGlomLevel value exists or not, or whatever value it it set to, has no meaning anymore after they enforce that policy.